# Is there any way to programmatically authenticate customers in Shopify?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, shopify, shopify-app

We have a custom app hosted in Firebase (Google's Backend as a service). We would like to use Shopify's authentication so the user doesn't have to create an account in the app as well as the Shopify store (where we require accounts).

**The key:** I need to have some mechanism (like an API) that I can use to have Shopify authenticate a user. (Assume the customer has already created an account in the Shopify store. Account creation will be handled by the normal Shopify process.)

I can create a page in my app to ask for email / pass. Is there some way to send this info (perhaps along with some sort of token generated from a private app) to authenticate the customer? I just need Shopify to confirm whether the email / pass is correct, so I can then 'login' the user into my Firebase app.

Any direction / thoughts / suggestions are greatly appreciated.

PS. Firebase offers a 'custom authentication' option, along with email, Google+, Facebook. The custom auth option requires sending user / pass to the authentication server, which in this case, would be Shopify.

**EDIT:** Based on the responses, edited to clarify that *I need some way to authenticate the user in Shopify*. Handling the custom auth into Firebase seems like a fairly straightforward task, once I receive some sort of signal from Shopify telling me the users email / pass is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Customer logs in to Shopify
2. Logged in Customer has an ID
3. Use App Proxy in your App to accept this ID using a secure callback
4. Use the Shopify API to look up the customer with the secure ID
5. If customer is found, they are then authentic and can use your App

Why is that not a useful and simple pattern for you to use?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed solution. I am a Shopify newbie, so bear with me... It appears that App Proxies can only be setup in Public Shopify apps - I really don't want a public app. Also, it seems like the Proxies are to display data back in the Shopify store? Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: You can install a proxy for a private app as long as your private app is hosted on a publicly available server with TLS. 
If your Firebase app isnt' meant to interact with a Shopify customer in the Shopify store then what is its purpose?

Comment: We want to collect other data from the customer (like height, weight, etc,) that is totally unrelated to them buying things from the store; subsequently, we may be receiving several other data points *per day* from customers. All of this data will be stored in Firebase.

Comment: The other issue that I'm not sure how to navigate is Step 5 above. I want the user to land *into* my app where I will be collecting said data. It looks like the proxy has to respond, and then the result is displayed within the store.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic use case for custom Auth with Firebase. You send email/pass to your backend, authenticate with shopify, on success create a custom token with the user's id (most likely using shopify's user id), send it back to the client which would `signInWithCustomToken` signing in to Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have edited the post to indicate that the part I need help with is the Shopify authentication.

Comment: Authenticating into Shopify is code you read in EVERY SINGLE theme ever. It is a form POST to Shopify... not something you fussabout.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look to [Shopify MultiPass](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/multipass). Although, you need Shopify Plus that is very expensive.

Comment: Saw that, but as you say, it's very expensive... 1,000s of $$ :(
Seems like this should be a fairly simple request to handle...